# Track campaigns with the help of javascript

Tags: google-analytics

I have issue to track campaign not with the help of url

```
http://domain.com/page?utm_campaign=xxx&utm_source=xxx&utm_medium=zzz
```

but javascript call.

According to the information given here [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCampContentKey) and my inpage google analytics universal code

```
<script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

                        ga('create', 'UA-zzz', 'domain.com');
                        ga('send', 'pageview');

                    </script>
```

I've tried to send inforation about campaign in many different ways, but all of them were unsuccessfull. I haven't found campaighn data in Analytics reports.

```
///
ga('_setCampNameKey', 'xxx'); ga('_setCampSourceKey', 'yyy'); ga('_setCampMediumKey', 'zzz');
///
ga('send', '_setCampNameKey', 'xxx'); ga('send', '_setCampSourceKey', 'yyy'); ga('send', '_setCampMediumKey', 'zzz');
///
ga('push', '_setCampNameKey', 'xxx'); ga('push', '_setCampSourceKey', 'yyy'); ga('push', '_setCampMediumKey', 'zzz');
///
ga('set', '_setCampNameKey', 'xxx'); ga('set', '_setCampSourceKey', 'yyy'); ga('set', '_setCampMediumKey', 'zzz');
///
ga('set', 'CampNameKey', 'xxx'); ga('set', 'CampSourceKey', 'yyy'); ga('set', 'CampMediumKey', 'zzz');
///
ga('set', 'campNameKey', 'xxx'); ga('set', 'campSourceKey', 'yyy'); ga('set', 'campMediumKey', 'zzz');
```

What is the right way to track campaign info?

Comment: Have you used the URL builder? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en Once you have correctly tagged your URL, and the link is clicked, you can see them right away in Real-Time reports under "Traffic Source" (they won't show up in standard reports for up to 24 hours).

Comment: I have the issue to track campaigns without url. And Real-Time reports don't show campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to find the answer to this, too, so even though this question is super old, I wanted to leave this here for others to find.

The analytics.js replacement for _setCampNameKey (and the other campaign tracking parameters) can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#campaignName

And this page has a full example of how to implement them:
http://randomproblems.com/how-to-setoverride-campaign-variables-in-google-analytics-universal-with-js/

gv0zd's answer is correct *except* that the Campaign parameters have to be set *before* sending the pageview. If you send them after (as in gv0zd's example), it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solving of the problem

```
    <script>
                (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-zzz', 'domain.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
///////
    ga('set', 'campaignName', 'XXX');
    ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'YYY');
    ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'ZZZ'); 

                        </script>
```